# Source of this "each" method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

In the first example on [this page](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this) Backbone document, the `messages` object uses a method `each`.  Which framework's method `each` used here: **underscore.js**, **backbone.js**, or **jquery**?

```
 var MessageList = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    var messages = this.collection;
    messages.on("reset", this.render, this);
    messages.on("add", this.addMessage, this);
    messages.on("remove", this.removeMessage, this);

    messsages.each(this.addMessage, this);
  }

});
```

In My Opinion

1.it cannot be underscore method since it use syntax of `_`

2.it cannot be jquery method since it use syntax of `$`

3.it cannot be backbone method since it uses underscore method

Comment: Is this a question, or did you per accident hit the "Ask question" button to answer a question?

Comment: i am asking question

Comment: Oh, ow well, than please explain a bit more, because this doesn't make sense.

Comment: its from underscrore.js http://underscorejs.org/#each

Comment: click on the link . in that messages is an object which is using each method. now which framework each method it is ? 
if it would be underscore then it would be like _.each 
if it would be jquery then it would be like  $each 
and i backbone.js doesnt have the each method .

Comment: so which each method is this. ?

Comment: Tightened wording, corrected grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much all the underscore methods can be used directly as Collections methods.

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-147

Answer (score 1):

If you check the backbone documentation you'll see that there is a list of underscore methods used in backbone. One of them is the `each` method, listed under **Underscore Methods (46)** paragraph. And in underscore [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#each) it's explicitly stated that the each method is actually an alias of Javascript [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method. And what it does?

The **underscore description**: *"It iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iteratee function."*

The **MDN description**: *"forEach() executes the provided callback once for each element present in the array in ascending order. It is not invoked for index properties that have been deleted or are uninitialized (i.e. on sparse arrays)."*

---

To answer your question why there isn't an underscore sign before the `each` method used in backbone relies on this small section from the Underscore [source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) code:

```
var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
};
```

What this function does, is instantiate a new object with the underscore sign if there is not already instantiated another one. If there is already an object with `_` sigh then it simply returns it.

Comment: if it was underscore method then it would be  message_.each

Comment: but there is no underscore sign

Comment: @mahendrapratapjewaria the underscore sign _does not matter_. The exact same function is proxied by Backbone, only it's being called without explicitly referencing the Undescore library. Why do you insist that there should be one?

Comment: Learn Javascript first. I provided all the needed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

> "Backbone proxies to Underscore.js to provide 46 iteration functions
>   on Backbone.Collection. They aren't all documented here, but you can
>   take a look at the Underscore documentation for the full details…"

http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: so is this underscore method? if it would be then we should use _.each like this .but here no underscore symbol

Comment: There is no underscore symbol because the method is _proxied_ as per what the documentation states. It seems that Backbone seems is using the OOP syntax so   all intents and purposed `_(messages).each` and `messsages.each` should be considered equal.